# PWM switch open loop gain plot buck topology

Tags: dc-dc-converter, ltspice, buck, stability

Open loop gain understanding, without using PWM switch and with using PWM switch model

Vramp =1V , Vin =5V, Modulator gain = Vin / Vramp = 5 , Fsw = 300Khz, Vout = 1.8V

[image: AC]

[image: Waveform]

Above image without PWM switch model. I got required behavior of loop gain.
I am assuming I should get the same using PWM Switch model (Filter load, and compensation are not changed). So I tried using it without adding modulator gain (Not required).

But the behavior of the loop gain was similar, but gain and phase values was not as measured in previous test case.

[image: pwm]

[image: waveform]

What am I missing here? Is my overall loop gain measurement correct in both cases?

Comment: What's the duty ratio value computed by source B1? It is very likely an overflow occurs in the bias point calculation hence the goofy ac answer with the PWM switch. The ramp generator can go but the output of the op-amp (source E2) must be clamped to less than 1 V (<100% duty ratio). The added RC on the op-amp output is quite unusual to me (the 1k/161n).

Comment: Duty ratio (transient sim) after clamping is -13.7V (This didn't help) . Yes you were right it says time step too small so I increased at sw node. Without clamps it used to be in order of 43.8kV I added RC network for opamp pole. Low frequency pole which provides necessary BW. Is this right?

Comment: I see, you need to rework your equivalent op-amp and clamp its output between 10 mV and 0.9 V (1% to 90% duty ratio). The best way to do it is to use a G-source and diodes. Please look at slide 44 in the [APEC seminar](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202015.pdf) I taught in 2015: the dc gain depends on \$g_m\$ and \$R_{OL}\$ while the pole on \$R_{OL}\$ and \$C_{p}\$. Then use perfect diodes (tweak N=10m for a 0-\$V_f\$) and set the clamps high and low. When computing the dc point, the \$D\$ input of the PWM switch will remain positive.

Comment: Since you're using LTspice, why not use the tools that it provides: `[Opamps]/UniversalOpamp2` will do an excellent job, even for level 1. As for the limiter, you could use G+D, but you also have the [`OTA`](http://ltwiki.org/?title=Undocumented_LTspice#OTA), with `vhigh/vlow+linear`, or `tanh()` limiting with `iout` or `isrc/isink`. You could even get creative with the s&h, but it will look confusing. :-)